# Is it possible to remove a message in a certain channel after 5 sec?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

is it possible
if someone posts a message
in a certain channel
that he then removes the message after 5 sec
but that the bot dont remove the bots messages

Here under is my message event
but it wont delete any messages
and i dont know what i have to do now

```
client.on("message", async message => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;


    var swearWords = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./data/swearWords.json"));

    var msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

    var embed1 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0d0041')
        .setDescription(`${message.author} Dat woord hoort hier niet thuis`)

    for (let i = 0; i < swearWords["vloekwoorden"].length; i++) {

        if (msg.includes(swearWords["vloekwoorden"][i])) {


            message.delete();

            return message.channel.send(embed1).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
        }

    }

    var channel = message.channel.id == "841337468585377882"

    var prefix = botConfig.prefix;

    var messageArray = message.content.split(" ");

    var command = messageArray[0];

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    // Command handler
    var arguments = messageArray.slice(1);

    var commands = client.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));

    if (commands) commands.run(client, message, arguments);

    if (channel) (msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));

});
```

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary with the deletion code.  Two possibilities.

1. Your word database isn't quite right, and it's not finding the swear word.
2. Your client doesn't have permission to delete.  You can check this one with message.deletable.

Comment: but swearwords work, this is only my message event. not my whole index

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're mixing `msg` with `message` and at the end you simply return an arrow function (`msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })`).

Also, instead of using `fs.readFileSync` to read a JSON file and then `JSON.parse` to parse it, you could simply use `require` that reads and parses a JSON file for you.

I've made a few changes to your code to make it more readable.

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  let { prefix } = botConfig;
  let CHANNEL_ID = '841337468585377882';
  // you don't need to different checks :)
  if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

  // you can simply require the JSON file, it'll also parse it for you
  let swearWords = require('./data/swearWords.json');
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0d0041')
    .setDescription(`${message.author} Dat woord hoort hier niet thuis`);

  // a for of loop is so much nicer
  for (let word of swearWords) {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)) {
      message.delete();

      return message.channel
        .send(embed)
        .then((msg) => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
    }
  }

  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  let command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  let commandToRun = client.commands.get(command);

  if (commandToRun) commandToRun.run(client, message, args);

  // don't return an arrow function, delete the original message
  if (message.channel.id === CHANNEL_ID)
    return message.delete({ timeout: 5000 });
});
```

Comment: do i have to delete my old messageEvent?

Comment: I only want to know how to remove every message in a certain channel after 5 seconds,

Comment: @stybo No, just change ``if (channel) (msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));`` to ``if (channel) {  return message.delete({ timeout: 5000 }); }``

Comment: @Zsolt Meszaros
This is not enirely correct ``you can simply require the JSON file, it'll also parse it for you``.  Reading a JSON with fs/JSON.Parse is not cached, require is cached.  Depending on how he is adding new swearwords to the list, this could break other functionality.  For example, if he manually edits the JSON while the bot is running, the bot will not update until its restarted when require is used, but with fs read, it will not require a bot restart.

Comment: @Tarazed but if i do that and i type in the channel nothing happens

Comment: @stybo type anything?  Your code is returning for anything that doesn't have your prefix, so only things typed with the prefix could ever be deleted.  If you want everything to be deleted, move the deletion before ``if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix))``

Comment: i dont understand you sir

Comment: @Tarazed when i replace your message event with mine i get this error

https://pastebin.com/QUq02haV

Comment: @stybo That wasn't my code, That is Zsolt's.  However, it looks like he didn't include the reference to Discord.

``const Discord = using('discord.js');`` and ``new Discord.MessageEmbed()``  without that reference it wouldn't know where to find it.

Comment: @Tarazed i have that, this is only my message event

Comment: You have the ``using`` statement but did you reference it in the ``new`` statement when creating a new instance of MessageEmbed?

Comment: Oh, yes, I usually import `MessageEmbed` directly like this: `const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')`, but I've just updated my code to use `Discord.MessageEmbed`